# Troubleshooting my Bridged Connection with Static IP for VM

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I am literally pulling my hair out trying to configure a bridged connection on a Virtual Machine (CentOS 6.7) with a Windows 7 Host.  For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get this working.  I am just so confused because the documentation on Google is different for each person that posts a tutorial.  I need to configure this bridged connection for a Static IP address.

Should I have an ifcfg-br0 that includes all of the important information, and then just ifcfg-eth0 that includes a reference to BRIDGE=br0?

Right now, I cannot ping the host (10.18.81.211) from the guest and I can't ping the guest from the host.

I have received a Static IP Address from my IT group: 10.18.81.251

I have started by configuring the bridged connection in the VMware settings:
[image]

Here is a photo of my ipconfig, and the Ethernet connection I want to bridge.
[image]

Here is my ifcfg-eth0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure firewalls aren't blocking? Can you reach outside (like Google)?

Comment: Hi @StanleyYu, how would I check whether or not my Firewall is getting in the way?  Does this have anything to do with `ICMP`?  I don't think I can ping `google.com` or `cnn.com`.  How would I fix a firewall issue?